# Create Plugin behind a custom button in Dynamics CRM

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a requirement that is needed a plugin in Dynamics CRM.
I want to create a plugin on the phonecall entity and after a click on the custom button, the plugin will create an incident with data of phonecall. how can do this please help me? I didn't find any solution or tutorial video on the internet that can help me to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get into custom coding a plugin, you might want to consider whether you an out-of-box workflow or Power Automate Flow to do what you need.

Whatever automation you choose, you could have it trigger on the setting of a two options field or a change in the Phone Call's status.

You can use [Ribbon Workbench](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx) to add a custom button and JavaScript to set that checkbox. Or, JavaScript could directly launch the workflow.

The [PCF Gallery](https://pcf.gallery) also has a number of button options which might be easier than the "DIY" option of Ribbon Workbench.

If you definitely need the plugin, you could register the plugin to fire on change of the checkbox, and again use a button to check on the checkbox.

Speaking of actions, you could also publish your Phone Call to Incident logic as a custom [action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/create-own-actions) and have the button call that action.

As you can see, there are plenty of options. It is typically a good idea to explore using configurable options like Power Automate Flow and PCF Gallery controls before custom coding a plugin.